# Generate tables, heat maps, in docx based on content of Word document

Tags: ms-word, full-text-search, docx

I need to generate word reports that have all kinds of tables and heat-maps that are based on the content in the report. For example, if an issue I describe is marked as "high", it has to go in the "high" area of heat-map. I have a docx generation solution in place similar to the one [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522627/whats-the-best-approach-to-generate-word-document-based-on-existing-templates), which works well until you start to adjust the contents and this requires re-generation of the tables, heat-maps, etc.

I am looking for viable approaches, re-usable libraries and anything else that can help update these tables, heat-maps when the content is changed.

The format of the report looks approximately like this (each number is a section):

```
1. Summary
1.1 Tables
2. Issues
2.1 Issue 1. In the issue there are issue attributes like
    severity, open/closed, etc
```

-BEGIN UPDATE-
The data for the tables and heat-maps comes from inside the write-up of the Issues. In general, you'd have somehting like this:

The Administrator password is blank
Difficulty: Low
Impact: High
CVSS: 10
Status:Open

-END UPDATE-

It seems to me that there could be a way to use the structure of the document and then parse out the text as tags and update the contents, but I have a feeling that this will be extremely error prone due to cut and paste, saving as, typos, etc.

Things I am not willing to consider:

- LaTeX or anything else that can't be done in Word
- Updating the data in the docx report generation toolkit (doesn't work in our workflow, must be able to edit things offline*)

*Plan B is to have a distributed, docx generating wiki which runs on each user's machine and then syncs up with the master repository, but you can see how this quickly becomes very complex.

Comment: I don't really get what kind of data you want to take as your input, and how you want to output it. If I understood it right, you want to generate a fresh `.docx` with tables and graphs, where the data must be taken from an other `.docx` document. Could you please give us a concrete example ?

Comment: @edi9999 i added an example, hope it makes sense.

Comment: Does the answer fits your need ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a way to import the data out of your document.

For this to work, you first need to get the full text of a document, here's a working example using [DocxGenJS](https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs), a library I have created: http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/textTagging.html#

This is the necessary code

```
var doc= new DocxGen(docData) 
text=doc.getFullText() //gets the fulltext as a string from the document 
document.getElementById("output").value=text
```

with the text variable, you could then use pattern matching to get the attributes of an issue:

```
patterns: "Difficulty:(Low|High|Medium)"
        : "Impact:(Low|High|Medium)"
```

After that, you can generate Heatmaps using for example `Canvas` in Javascript.

Comment this if you need more info about a specific point.